# Iterating all elements of list with other elements in Python

Tags: python, windows

I am working with `Python 2.7.12`

I have the following list:

```
t = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to have following output:

```
1+1, 1+2, 1+3, 1+4, 1+5, 2+2, 2+3, 2+4, 2+5, 3+3, 3+4, 3+5, 4+4, 4+5
```

I tried:

```
zip(t,t[1:])
```

but the output was:

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Then, I also tried:

```
 zip(t,t)
```

but the output was:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
```

Comment: t is not a list here but a tuple. Assuming thats a type do we really know that input list is always sorted?

Comment: Dear Frankyjuang, My question is related to iteration of one element of list with rest of the elements. The question you have mentioned is between TWO lists.

Comment: Then just set `list2 = list1`.

Answer (score 1):

May be
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]

```
for i in list1:
    for j in list1[i-1:]:
        print str(i)+"+"+str(j)
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. Many Thanks.

Comment: Glad, I could help! Upvote or Accept this answer if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two for `loops` to iterate through the `list` as the following:

```
t = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
result = []
for i in xrange(len(t)-1):
    for j in xrange(i, len(t)):
        result.append(t[i] + '+' + t[j])
print ', '.join(result)
```

output:

```
1+1, 1+2, 1+3, 1+4, 1+5, 2+2, 2+3, 2+4, 2+5, 3+3, 3+4, 3+5, 4+4, 4+5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
t = ('1','2','3','4','5')
sums = [i[0]+"+"+i[1] for i in list(combinations_with_replacement(t, 2))]
```

Output:

```
['1+1', '1+2', '1+3', '1+4', '1+5', '2+2', '2+3', '2+4', '2+5', '3+3', '3+4', '3+5', '4+4', '4+5', '5+5']
```

Comment: Dear Damian, Thanks. I tried it and output is  ['1+2', '1+3', '1+4', '1+5', '2+3', '2+4', '2+5', '3+4', '3+5', '4+5'].  Still missing 1+1, 2+2, 3+3, 4+4, 5+5. Any idea?

Comment: I believe you may be referring to another user, but I have changed my code above to get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Dear Ajax1234, The solution is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark this answer as accepted so other users know it has been answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

t = ('1','2','3','4','5')

for t1, t2 in itertools.product(t, t):
    if t1 <= t2:
        print('%s + %s' % (t1, t2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming t is a list and not always sorted.

```
t.sort()
t_len = len(t)
output = []
for i in xrange(t_len - 1):
   j = 1 if i == 0 else i
   for k in xrange(j, t_len):
      output.append(str(t[i]) + "+" + str(t[j]))
print output
```

Answer (score 0):

In three lines:

```
list = range(1,6)
lists = [list[(i-1):] for i in list]
output = [str(i[0]) + '+' +str(j) for i in lists for j in i]
```

Comment: Or simply `output = [str(i)+'+'+str(j) for i in list for j in list[i-1:]]`